# How to generate a list with own data type in haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell, recursion

I am trying to create an infinite list with my own data type in haskell

```
data Color = Black | White       deriving (Show, Eq)
data Cell  = Empty | Stone Color deriving (Show, Eq)

makeRow :: Int -> Row
makeRow 0 = []
makeRow n = take n (repeat Cell Empty)
```

And it gives me the error :

```
Data constructor not in scope: Cell
```

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service. You try first, and show us your attempt and explain why you believe you can't make progress. We'll help you take whatever the single next step is, then you drive progress again.

Comment: The [Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch20.html#x28-23300020.4) section on building lists might help further your research.

Comment: @DanielWagner I have modified my code and tried... Could you please check it now? Thank you!

Comment: @user3637052 Given that this question has had multiple close votes, it would have been better to ask this improved version as a new question. It's a much better question now, but keep this in mind, please.

Comment: @AJFarmar I disagree. Close votes are supposed to encourage edits, and it does nobody any good to have a bad, closed question lying around instead of improving it. Even if it were actually closed, that's what reopening is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because `Cell` is - indeed - not a value constructor. Just use plain `Empty` instead (note that you don't write `Bool True` or `Bool False` - you just write `True` or `False`).